# Java Eclipse Maven adding dependency causes the app to fail to run

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am in a Java project that uses Maven. When I add a local dependency to the `pom.xml` file, the app fails to run.

I add the submodule to the dependency list in the `pom.xml` package, click run in eclipse and it gives me an error. When I remove the dependency from `pom.xml` file it runs fine.

My question is mainly when I add a dependency to the `pom.xml` file do I have to do it thru Eclipse in a way or is it fine to write it out? Also after adding the dependency do I need to run a `mvn install` again?

Comment: "_it gives me an error_" - You can [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of the POM (so we know what you are adding and how you are adding it). You can also provide the error message (as formatted text, not a screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Maven Plugin doesn't see your changes in the pom.xml file automatically. Depending on your changes to the pom.xml file, you need at least to do manually

`Right Click on the Project -> Maven -> Update project`.

[image: maven update project]

Sometimes it doesn't help, and you need to do `mvn install` and after that `Maven -> Update project`.